# create readmore button with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON object that has many rows and I'd like to add to the scope more and more of these object (lets say every click to add 2 more rows from the main json).

I have the `respone` object, the includes, the main JSON (with all the rows) and the scope `$scope.users` from where I get all users with `ng-repeat="user in users"`.

```
<button ng-click="readMore()">Read More</button>

$scope.readMore = function() {
    /* HOW CAN I ADD HERE INTO `$scope.users` to have 2 more rows ? */
};
```

And how do I start `$scope.users` with only 2 rows (that come from the object `response`?

thanks

Comment: Did you try simply pushing two new rows to users array $scope.users.push([row1, row2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limitTo` filter please see example below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.limit = 2;
$scope.max = false;
  $scope.readMore = function() {

    if ($scope.limit < $scope.rows.length) {
      $scope.limit =$scope.limit  + 2;
       if ($scope.limit >= $scope.rows.length) {
       
        $scope.max = true;
       }
      
    }
    else {
      
      $scope.max = true;
      }

  };

  $scope.rows = [

    {
      rowid: 1,
      text: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. "
    }, {
      rowid: 2,
      text: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. "
    }, {
      rowid: 3,
      text: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. "
    }, {
      rowid: 4,
      text: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. "
    }, {
      rowid: 5,
      text: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. "
    }, {
      rowid: 6,
      text: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. "
    }

  ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="item in rows | limitTo: limit">{{item.rowid}}). {{item.text}}</p>
    <button ng-click="readMore()" ><span ng-if="!max">Read More</span><span ng-if="max">End</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```